# How to escape (to initial calling place) from a recursive function in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, recursion, escaping, closures

```
var currentCount = 0
let totalCount = 100

func myEscapingRecursiveFunction(_ json: String, done: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    
currentCount+=1

    if currentCount == totalCount {
        
        done(true)
    }
    else {
        myEscapingRecursiveFunction("xyz") { done in
        // what should I do here????
    } 
}
```

**Calling**

```
 // (Initially called here)
myEscapingRecursiveFunction("xyz") { done in 
    if done {
        print("completed") // I want to get response here after the recursion is finished
    }
}
```

I want my function to escape only when the current count is equal to total count, otherwise it should recurse, ***the problem is that I want to get response in place where it was initially called***, but it will always execute the completion handler code where it was last called. here: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass the same escaping block to your recurse function.

so call your function like this.

```
myEscapingRecursiveFunction("xyz", done: done)
```